Using .CopyPicture on a variable range
I have a worksheet (A) where the range is B1:J43. There is code that copies data from a different worksheet (B) into specific rows in A. Column B contains lane numbers for physical location referencing. There is additional code that will sort the data based on criteria in column H. I am trying to then use the .CopyPicture code to only copy that range where there is data in B1:J??. I tried the code below but it only copies one blank cell. Any help will be appreciated.
Sub Snip_SDT_Sort()

Dim SDTLR

SDTLR = Worksheets("SDT Status").Cells(Sheet18.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    With Sheet18
        .Range("B" & SDTLR).CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap
    End With

End Sub

Row B1:J1 is a header row. Column B1:B43 will always have data. There is code that copies data and sorts it. The code I am trying should create a snip of the data in B1:(last used row of J).

"B" & SDTLR is one cell, right? Also why the inconsistency between Worksheets("SDT Status") and Sheet18?

SDT Status and Sheet18 are the same sheet. I am building my code based off of code in other worksheets as reference to try and get this to work. I should also say that I am not a proficient coder, just on the weekends.

IIUC, Range("B1:J" & SDTLR).

If B:B has the last cell on the same row as H:H, what is shows is normal. You copy the picture of the next cell after the last one, which is empty. Please, better describe (in words) what would you like copying... What should we understand from "copy that range where there is data in B1:J??"?  Do you want  a picture to that range, but excluding the empty cells?

Ok. I did not do a great job with the question. Column B will ALWAYS have data from B1:B43. C2:J43 will not always have data (hence variable range). I do not want to get a snip of the entire range, just the used range. However, the problem is that it seems I will always get the snip of B1:J43 because of column B. I hope this clarifies what I am trying to achieve. Sorry to @BigBen for not being more clear.

Your code is determining the last row based on column H, not column B though.

But I also need the corresponding data in column B for the used range I am trying to get the snip of.

@BigBenI was referencing column H because I know that with my sort, that column will provide the "last used row". At least that was my thought process in trying the code.

I updated the original question. I hope that makes better sense.

If you want to the last used row of column J, then change "H" to "J" in the line SDTLR = Worksheets("SDT Status").Cells(Sheet18.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row + 1

@BigBen I tried that, but my original problem still exists where the snip includes the entire range of B1:J43.

Then J42 is populated. Does it have a formula in it returning ""?

@BigBen No it does not. And to verify this, I highlighted all the "empty" cells and clicked delete just to make sure. I do not run any formulas in this range at all. And the result was the same, a snip of the entire range.

.End(xlUp) stops at a non-empty cell (or row 1 if all cells are empty). So there's something in that cell in column H.

I think this is where the issue lies: I have static data in column B1:B43. This data will always be there. How do we get the code to work past that?
